# wpf extended toolkit BusyIndicator binding to property

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, wpftoolkit

I have a BusyIndicator, which i bind the IsBusy to my Busy property in my view model.

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding Busy}" x:Name="busyBox" Grid.Row="2"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" BusyContent="Contacting Server" >
    </xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

I switch busy to true as I start a webservice call (asynch), and set it to false on the callback.

This works great the 1st time, everytime after that it doesnt display the busy indicator anymore. I added a thread.sleep in the callback (just in x=case it was moving too fast the 2nd time).

I know that my property is notifying correctly because other bound controls and working as expected. it just seems that the busyindicator is good for only one use

(btw i am using mvvm light toolkit v3)

VIEW MODEL CODE

```
this.Busy = true; //This proverty is declared correctly with notifications etc
IPersonSearchService searcher = new PersonSearchService(); //class that does my      webservice, ad i pass it a callback method from my UI (see below)
searcher.FindByPersonDetails(ps, GetAllPeopleCallback);


private void GetAllPeopleCallback (PersonSearchResult result, Exception e)
    {
        this.Busy = false;
        ((Models.PersonSearch)this.Model).Persons = result.Persons; //bound to my grid
         CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();  //i need to do this to make a button who's canexecute command binding happen         
    }
```

This is the class that hits the webservice

```
class PersonSearchService : IPersonSearchService
{
    public void FindByPersonDetails(WSPersonSearch.PersonSearch ps, Action<PersonSearchResult, Exception> Callback)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            WSPersonSearch.PersonSearch search = (WSPersonSearch.PersonSearch)args.Argument;
            PersonSearchWebServiceClient wc = new PersonSearchWebServiceClient();
            PersonSearchResult r = wc.FindByPersonDetails(ps);
            args.Result = r;
        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            PersonSearchResult result = (PersonSearchResult)args.Result;
            Callback(result, null);
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

everything else on the ui behaves nicely. my buttons activate/deactivate correctly. my grid gets updated nicely etc etc

Comment: Can you post code for ViewModel of your callback?

Comment: If the BusyIndicator control is the problem, you can always create your own control. It is not that hard as it appears (you just have to put your Busy indicator and your View content in a grid without rows and bind the Visibility of the indicator to your Busy property).

Comment: I think it is not the BusyIndicator, maybe could be an asynchronization thread problem. Maybe with the visual threads of WPF. Maybe it solve using a `SynchronizationContext` for set the `IsBusy` property back to false.

Comment: Also you must add the DataContext item's code.

Comment: @RaulOtaño i think you are right. i did a little sample app without the asynch and the indicator behaves as i would expect. I am using a backgroundWorker to do my webservice call. busy gets set to true in the DoWork() method, busy gets to false in a callback method passed the class and kicked off by RunWorkerCompleted() method. process fires off in RunWorkerAsync(). i thought that the RunWorkerCompleted ran inside the UI thread automagically? or should I be doing something special?  ill post some sample code

Comment: if it help at all, the UI is inside a frame that was set by a Navigate method to an instance of my usercontrol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i solved it.
It seems (and is often the case) and by posting the sample code above (removing all my testing mess) i solved it.

ok the model works, but because i am speaking to a web service and after the 1st call my webservice call is uber uber fast after that it was mooving too fast for me to see the bsy infdicator.

so to get around that...... i got lazy and added a sleep. but i put the sleep in the callback. so since the callback gets fired in the ui thread it was blocking at the wrong point. the busy indicator had already come and gone by the time it hit the sleep.

so i moved it into the DoWork method (which is outside of the ui threqad) and the busy indicator sstays.

silly me. thanks the the advice fellows!